# Selecting a tree and ordering children using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id          integer serial primary key
    parent_id   integer
    name        text    not null
    ordering    integer not null
);
```

I want to select all categories, but indent the names of child categories and put the child categories under their parents. Within the same level, they should be ordered by `ordering`.

I currently have the following query, but the returned child categories are not in the correct order. Instead, they are being ordered *absolutely* rather than *relative to their siblings*.

```
WITH RECURSIVE recurse_categories(id, level, name, ordering) AS (
    SELECT id, 0 AS level, name, ordering
      FROM categories
     WHERE parent_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.id, level + 1, c.name, c.ordering
      FROM categories AS c
      JOIN recurse_categories rc
        ON rc.id = c.parent_id
)

  SELECT id, repeat('→', level) || ' ' || name AS name
    FROM recurse_categories
ORDER BY ordering
```

How can I do the ordering correctly?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accumulate ordering into string:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recurse_categories(id, level, name, ordering) AS (
    SELECT id, 0 AS level, name, lpad(ordering::text, 10, '0') as ordering
      FROM categories
     WHERE parent_id IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.id, level + 1, c.name, rc.ordering || '→' || lpad(c.ordering::text, 10, '0') as ordering
      FROM categories AS c
      JOIN recurse_categories rc
        ON rc.id = c.parent_id
)

  SELECT id, repeat('→', level) || ' ' || name AS name, ordering
    FROM recurse_categories
ORDER BY ordering
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f8f4c/4)

Comment: I used `array[ordering] AS ordering` and `rc.ordering || c.ordering` instead.

Comment: yes, it could be done too, it's just solution with string will work in other RDBMS (like SQL Server, which don't have arrays)